# How to filter a table by multiple (dynamic) conditions from another table?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am stuck trying to get more flexibility in my queries.

I have facts table:

| enabled | country | color | count | vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | **DE** | yellow | **one** | car |
| no | FR | blue | **one** | car |
| no | **DE** | ***red*** | **one** | ***bike*** |
| yes | **DE** | ***green*** | **one** | car |
| yes | ES | yellow | **one** | car |
| yes | **IT** | yellow | two | car |
| yes | **IT** | yellow | **one** | car |

and in Excel I also would like to have two simple configuration tables:

1. Table: ***RemoveRecordsByValue***
   a table with field-value pairs, that act as conditions to remove those records if there is any match.

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| vehicle | bike |
| color | green |
| color | red |

2. Table: **KeepRecordsByValue**
   a table with potentially

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| country | DE |
| country | IT |
| count | one |

The expected table would be:

| enabled | country | color | count | vehicle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | DE | yellow | one | car |
| yes | IT | yellow | one | car |

Anybody might have a hint how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

```
***FactsTable***

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WqkwtVtJRcnEFEpWpOTn55UBGfl4qkExOLFKK1YlWyssHctyCgERSTmkqdmmw/qLUFLhsUmZ2Klgayfz0otTUPAz9EAWuwbgdAFHhGYKsoqQ8n4AKJDNiAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [enabled = _t, country = _t, color = _t, count = _t, vehicle = _t]),
    Result = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"enabled", type text}, {"country", type text}, {"color", type text}, {"count", type text}, {"vehicle", type text}})
in
    Result


***RemoveRecordsByValue***

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKkvNyEzOSVXSUUrKzE5VitWJVkrOz8kvAgqkF6Wm5qGIFKWmKMXGAgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [field = _t, value = _t]),
    Result = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"field", type text}, {"value", type text}})
in
    Result


***KeepRecordsByValue***

let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSs4vzSspqlTSUXJxVYrVQRbwDEEIALn5ealKsbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [field = _t, value = _t]),
    Result = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"field", type text}, {"value", type text}})
in
    Result
´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a million ways to do this. Here's one

Load both KeepRecordsByValue and RemoveRecordsByValue as separate powerquery queries

Load the facttable. Add index. Click select index and unpivot other columns.

Merge facttable with RemoveRecordsByValue using left outer join and expand one field.

Merge results with KeepRecordsByValue using left outer join and expand one field.

[image]

Group results on index, and combine the expanded fields from above

[image]

Filter out anything with text in the RemoveRecordsByValue combined column and anything with a blank in the KeepRecordsByValue combined column

[image]

That table has the only index items you want to keep. Merge that back against original facttable with inner join on index

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Value"},RemoveRecordsByValue,{"field", "value"},"RemoveRecordsByValue",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded RemoveRecordsByValue" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "RemoveRecordsByValue", {"value"}, {"Remove"}),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded RemoveRecordsByValue",{"Attribute", "Value"},KeepRecordsByValue,{"field", "value"},"KeepRecordsByValue",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded KeepRecordsByValue" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "KeepRecordsByValue", {"value"}, {"keep"}),
Grouped= Table.Group(#"Expanded KeepRecordsByValue", {"Index"}, {{"Remove", each Text.Combine([Remove]," "), type text},{"Keep", each Text.Combine([keep]," "), type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Grouped, each ([Remove] = "") and ([Keep] <> "")),
#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"},"zzz",JoinKind.Inner),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries2",{"Index", "zzz"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Hi horseyride, thanks for your feedback.   Using the joins is an interesting way to solve it.  I did not thought about it yet, because I tried not to touch the whole tables until I reduced it by filtering    for performance reasons.    (facts table is 2x 5 MB external xlsx)

Going to check and try out your solution tomorrow.

One thing I noticed:    KeepRecordsByValue      is not meant to keep by any value,   but  if a field is defined, one of it's  values has to be there. 
i.e.:    if country is defined ,   the record has to be with DE  or IT ,   but a different one is not valid.

Comment: The way I tried to solve it the whole day was by using one Table.Select  for each KeepRecordsTable and RemoveRecordsTable    in combination with   nested / recursive  List.Contains   and referencing the   ColumnNames or RecordFields by using   their  texts to reference to column (by field) and compare against value.
  `  filterTable = Table.SelectRows(factsTable, (row) => 
        .....some recursive ....... (recordList, (columnToFilter) => 
            List.Contains(columnToFilter[Value], Record.Field(row, columnToFilter[Field]) ))),